# Image not Showing React native Expo

Tags: json, react-native, expo

React Native Code

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.carlist}>
        {api.map((item, key) => (
          <View key={item.brand} style={styles.photo}>
            <Text>{item.brand}</Text>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.logo }} />
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
```

JSON file Data

```
    {
    "brand": "Volvo",
    "logo":"https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiyE3dAIjI8lgRtQot0nBaNTeCLb?e=O2r7fz",
    "models" :[
        {
            "name":"XC90",
            "link":"https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiyE3dAIjI8lgV6XcQOmso1W2rta?e=wXTM4d"
        },
        {
            "name":"XC60",
            "link":"https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiyE3dAIjI8lgWjRXFT6G9NEzbS4?e=ELJ4HZ"
        },
        }
```

The URL is supplied correctly but the image does not appear on the screen. Images are stored in one drive. I have tried with images on the internet as well but none of those appear on the screen. I want to take JSON data and display it in grid form if any content that helps with that would be helpful as well.  Expo Documentation shows it to be like this but in loop it does not appear.

Comment: The `image` you are trying to load needs an `Authorization`.  That's the reason its not loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `image` you are trying to load needs an `Authorization`. Yes, it will show up if you paste the URL in the browser but for the `Image` component you need some kind of `Authorization` from OneDrive. That's the reason it's not loading.

**Read More about Image Headers [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#network-requests-for-images)**

And also make sure you provide Dimensions to the images in order to show them. As mentioned in the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#network-images), **Unlike with static resources, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image.**

For Example -

```js
<Image source={{ uri: SomeURI }} />
// This will not load and the image would not be shown.
```

```js
<Image source={{ uri: SomeURI }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
// This will load perfectly and the image will be shown.
```

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/image-uri)

Comment: Thanks, I was lacking style element and also one drive has a separate URL for embedding which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you should add header 'accept':

```
<Image source={{ uri: userInfo.picture, headers: { 'Accept': 'image/*'} }} style={styles.profilePic} />
```

as shown in [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#network-requests-for-images)